# Issue Can't Activate Account using library myth/auth codeigniter 4 from Lonnie Ezell

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

Can anyone help me? I use library myth/auth codeigniter 4 from Lonnie Ezell , I activate the account activation feature by email. The activation email has been successfully sent, but when I click "Activate Account" it enters the login page, when logging in, it always appears "This user account is not yet activated. Resend activation message one more time."

CI_VERSION = '4.0.4'
I'm using development and localhost mode

Thank you for your attention

Comment: Have you tried contacting them?

Comment: I have included the issue on his github, but now problem solved, I installed the library manually without using composer. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to install myth/auth manually not with composer